# What did the Super Tactical Droid encountered by the Jedi mean by his words?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels

In the latest *Rebels* episode, the crew encountered what's left of a surviving Separatist force, commanded by a Super Tactical Droid.

Rex questioned the droid commander how he is still active, given the shutdown signal transmitted after Order 66 was executed. The droid replied that he suspected a "Republic trick", hence preventing the shutdown.

What did he mean? How did he do it? Did he anticipate the signal and disabled his army from following the signal, or was he responsible for transmitting it to the individual droids and thus refused to do so due to his suspicions? What does his words mean?

Comment: Should this have [tag:the-clone-wars]? It’s not really about the events of that show, even if Super Tactical Droids might have showed up in there.

Comment: I couldn’t find an answer to this in the latest Rebels Recon, but they did provide an answer for people who were confused by all the various people named Antilles.

Comment: @Adamant It may be irrelevant, but this episode actually pays homage to its predecessor Star Wars: The Clone Wars, as the title logo is stylized after its predecessor and the ending theme is the same one from The Clone Wars.

Answer (score 11):

Kalani was a [Super Tactical Droid (STD)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Super_tactical_droid), which are known for their intelligence.

> **Kanan Jarrus:** "I think the commander's a super tactical droid."
>   **Rex:** "Ah, you're right. He is."
>   **Ezra Bridger:** "Is that bad?"
>   **Rex:** "It's really bad. That droid's extremely intelligent."
>   *―Kanan Jarrus, Clone Captain Rex, and Ezra Bridger (Star Wars Rebels, "The Last Battle")*

According to the [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Super_tactical_droid), they were programmed with Separatist beliefs and designed to calculate a possible battle-winning solution, and are also given a greater degree of autonomy.

The Super Tactical Droid, and legion of still active droids, in question were stationed in Agamar, a planet located in the Outer Rim Territories, when Order 66 was issued and Darth Vader was sent to Mustafar to give the shutdown order.

Given that Super Tactical Droid generals are given a greater degree of autonomy, Kalani assessed - correctly - that the bizarre and random shut-down order must have been nothing more than a Republic trick, so he ignored it and did not relay it to the rest of the droids under his command.

**In short:** Super Tactical Droids are extremely intelligent/autonomous, and the shut-down order was bizarre and random, so Kalani assessed (correctly) that it was a trick.

Comment: +1 - Whether the shut-down signal was a ruse or not is kind of a matter of political perspective.

Comment: @MarkRogers In my answer I am discussing the perspective, motives and design of Kalani, the Super Tactical Droid, and even mention that they are programmed with Separatist beliefs, so when I say that Kalani assessed it correctly, I am implying "from a Separatist's/Kalani's perspective".

Comment: But would other Super Tactical Droids not also belay the order?